# SharePoint IF AND OR formula

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have been working on a calculated column formula and have gotten stuck.

I have a list with several columns the formula is looking at. 
First column is a Due Date column that is a simple calculated column of Created date + 4 days
The Second column is a Completed column. The three options here are empty(blank), Working and Yes
The formula I'm working on is for a Reassign column which will ether be a Yes or No. The conditions are If the Due Date is greater than the Modified date and the Completed column is ether Working or empty(blank) then the Assigned column should be No. IF the conditions are not met then reassign column should be Yes

The below formula works except if the Completed column is empty(blank). I've tried using ISBLANK but have had no luck. I believe it maybe a simple formatting issue but any help would be greatly appreciated.

=IF(AND([Due Date]>Modified,OR(Completed="Working",Completed=" ")),"No","Yes")

Comment: If you're still looking for help, I recommend asking for more guidance on SharePoint.StackExchange.com That community is a bit more focused on the ins and outs of SharePoint as a platform, whereas this community is more focused on programming. There's some overlap, but it sounds like your question is more suited for their advice. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your calculated formula would work with using `ISBLANK`

`IF(AND([Due Date]>Modified,OR([Completed]="Working",ISBLANK([Completed]))),"No","Yes")`

I always try to use `ISBLANK`, instead of checking for `=" "`.

Comment: I tried this formula for the calculated column Reassign and it returns No on all items in the list regardless of due date and completed status.  I had placed the [] around completed but SharePoint removes them when saving, not sure if this makes a difference.                                             =IF(AND([Due Date]>Modified,OR(Completed="Working",ISBLANK(Completed))),"No","Yes")

Comment: I'd have to see what was in your list data to know why this was occurring, but the formula works. How is your Due Date column set up? Is Completed a Yes/No field, or is it single line of text? If it's Yes/No then check for TRUE or FALSE, instead.  Also, Excel is a great tool for testing and working with these formulas, btw.

Comment: Sure i understand. The Due Date column is calculated column of modified Date + 4 days. So the formula looks like =Modified+4 and returns date and time - 5/2/2016 9:45 AM. The Completed column is a choice. Default is blank with choices Yes and Working. I could try changing this to a Yes/No, however Working would make more sense to the users.

Comment: So, your Due Date calculated column would always be greater than the Modified Date, so why would you even check that condition?

Comment: What this formula is meant to do is keep an item in a specific users list they have been assigned if they are working on it, even if it's past the due date. However if they have not worked on it, I.E. If the modified date has not changed and the completed has not been changed to working then it drops off their list to be reassigned to someone else.

Comment: And to your comment on the brackets [], it does not make a difference. You will see SharePoint include them if you insert a column through the calculated column editor, but it removes them when the formula is saved.

Comment: Yeah, the brackets are only really useful if there's a space in the column name. If there are no spaces, they'll get trimmed out.

Comment: I agree with @Thriggle 's advice. I think some custom filtered views would better accomplish what your are trying to solve. You can also reference Created By or other People Picker column with [Me] in views to only show that user his/her items in a view.

Comment: Yes referencing [Me] is exactly what I'm doing for the individual view so they only see items assigned to them. However filtering as Thiggle suggests is not showing new items with a future due date and no completed and is showing items past their due date with no completed column info, which should not show since they need to be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

To make things simpler, I would flip your logic. Instead of checking that `Completed` is blank or "Working", check that it's **not** "Yes".

`=IF(AND([Due Date]>Modified,NOT(Completed="Yes")),"No","Yes")`

Comment: I tried this formula for the calculated column Reassign and it returns No on all items in the list regardless of due date and completed status.         =IF(AND([Due Date]>Modified,NOT(Completed="Yes")),"No","Yes")

Comment: @MikeB Is your Due Date column configured to return a date?

Comment: Yes the Due Date column is calculated column of Created Date + 4 days. It is returning Date and time, ex. 5/2/2016 9:45 AM

Comment: Sorry it's not Created Date + 4 it's modified, so formula for due date is =Modified+4

Comment: @MikeB In that case `Due Date` is **always** going to be greater than `Modified`... So why should we even bother performing the comparison?

Comment: What this formula is meant to do is keep an item in a specific users list they have been assigned if they are working on it, even if it's past the due date. However if they have not worked on it, I.E. If the modified date has not changed and the completed has not been changed to working then it drops off their list to be reassigned to someone else.

Comment: What's interesting is this version of the formula almost works. =IF(AND([Due Date]>Modified,OR(Completed="Working",Completed=" ")),"No","Yes"). Except if the due date is say 5/6 currently, these are being marked with a Yes for Reassign.

Comment: @MikeB It sounds like what you're really looking for is a way to track aging. You don't want to compare `Created` to `Modified`, you want to compare `Modified` to `[Today]`. This cannot be done on a calculated column, but it can be done in a view. Create a view that shows items where `Modified` is less than `[Today]-4` and `Completed` is not equal to `Yes` and that will show you the items that need to be reassigned.

Comment: Great idea, however when I setup the filter as listed above I lose the list items with a due date of 5/6 currently. These items Completed column is blank since they have not been started yet. It also still shows items past their due date that have a blank Completed. An item with this data should be reassigned not be showing on their list

Comment: @MikeB Do you have an "Assigned To" field? You could add another condition to your view filters so that the view will also show any unassigned items. Something like "...OR `Assigned To` equals (leave the text box blank)". Good luck!

Comment: Yes I believe what your asking about is a column name simply Rep. Name. This is a required field anytime a list item is added or if the item is being reassigned. However I'm not sure how this can solve the situations where the assigned person is still working on a list item past it's due date, the assigned to field would not be changed in these cases. If you could explain further on how I could utilize it for this that would be great, Thanks for all your input into this issue.

Comment: @MikeB Sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought you were saying that it was a problem that list items with a due date of 5/6 weren't showing up in your filtered view of items that need to be reassigned; I assumed that was because they hadn't been assigned to anybody yet. You should set up multiple distinct views, including a view to see the items that need reassignment (that is, ones that haven't been worked on in the last 4 days), a different view to show completed items, and a different view to show active items (ones that have been created or modified on in the last 4 days).

Comment: ok this is a good enough solution for me. I can embed these list views in a page for the individuals to use. Thank you very much for all your input and brainstorming. Sometimes the simplest ideas are best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

```
=IF(AND([Due Date]>Modified,OR(Completed="Working",Completed=0)),"No","Yes")
```